apply bar or tilde to symbol only (ignore subscript)
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ \bar{S_{i,k}} $

\end{document}

What I want is to span the bar only over the letter S. Obviously, the solution to this is $\bar{S}_{i,k}$. But suppose we have a generic command
\newcommand{\makeBar}[1]{\bar{#1}}

and we call it
\makeBar{B_i}

In the latter case, again the bar spans the entire expression and not only the symbol B. Well, we could do $\makeBar{B}_i$ but this is not preferred my solution since I want to control the majority of my coding via macros.
Is there a nice solution to span the bar (or tilde,...) only over the symbol, ignoring possible sub- or superscripts adjacent to the symbol?

Why not just stick with \bar B_i, as designed?

\makeBar B_i should also only take the first symbol into the command, but only works as a solution if the bar always needs to be over one symbol only

You can play with regular expressions, available with expl3:
\cs_new:Nn \simon_apply_to_symb:nn
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tempa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { [^\_\^]+ }
      { \c{ #1 } \{ \0 \} } \l_tempa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl
  }

Example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \simon_apply_to_symb:nn
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tempa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { [^\_\^]+ }
      { \c{ #1 } \{ \0 \} } \l_tempa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewApplyToSymbolCommand}{ m m }
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand{ #1 }{ m }{ \simon_apply_to_symb:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewApplyToSymbolCommand{\makebar}{\bar}
\NewApplyToSymbolCommand{\makewidetilde}{\widetilde}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mysymb}{\alpha BC}

\begin{align*}
  \bar{S_{i,k}}       && \widetilde{S_{i,k}}        \\
  \makebar{S_{i, k}}  && \makewidetilde{S_{i, k}}   \\
  \makebar{S^{i, k}}  && \makewidetilde{S^{i, k}}   \\
  \makebar{\mysymb_{i, k}^{2}} && \makewidetilde{\mysymb_{i, k}^{2}} \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Note it does not work with double subscripts like \makebar{{S_i}_j}
